# Alpinejs two common components and parent Component bind data

Tags: alpine.js

I have modal inside is a form with hidden inputs and two  timepicker  start and end time. I want to bind it to the start and end time selected from the Component to the parent component.

When timepicker sets the time value I need to update the parent Component.

How can I pass start_time and end_time from parent component to respective timepicker and bind on update in child component?

```html
<div x-data="{ start_time: '10:00 AM';end_time:'12:00 PM' }">
    <input  x-model="start_time" name="start_time"  type="hidden">
    <input  x-model="end_time" name="end_time"  type="hidden">
    <!-- Start Timepicker  -->
    <div x-data="{time:null}">
          ...Timepicker sets the start time value
    </div>
     <!-- End Timepicker -->
    <div x-data="{time:null}">
        ...Timepicker sets the end time value      
    </div>
</div>
```

Can I pass hidden input x-refs to the child component?

```html
<input  x-model="start_time" name="start_time"  type="hidden" x-ref="refStartTime">
<input  x-model="end_time" name="end_time"  type="hidden" x-ref="refEndTime">
```

Can Child component update the hidden input on the parent Component?

I want to know if possible with x-subscribe or x-modelable or $disptach or x-refs or x-bind

Answer (score 1):

As reported in the Alpine.js [documentation](https://alpinejs.dev/essentials/state#nesting-data): *"Data is nestable in Alpine"*
So one option may be to let the time-picker modify the parent *data*, an idea may be to pass an optional value to the time-picker which if present will represent some sort of *"reference"* to the *parent data variable* to update

Another option can be using [custom events / $dispatch](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/dispatch): when the inner component changes his value it dispatches a custom event with some parameters, then the event is managed by the outer component

Here a simple example of these techniques:

```html
<div style="display:flex;flex-wrap: wrap;width: 200px;border: 1px solid black;">

    <div x-data="{ open: true, counters: {counter: 0, unused_counter: 999} }"
         @open-close.window="counters.counter+=$event.detail.increment; open=!open"
         style="min-width: 50%;border: 1px solid blue;"
    >
        <div>
            Counter:
            <input type="text" disabled x-model="counters.counter">
        </div>

        <button x-data="{ related_counter: 'counter'}"
                @click="if (typeof related_counter !== 'undefined') counters[related_counter]++; open=!open"
        >
            INNER-BUTTON
        </button>

        <div x-data>

            <span x-show="open">OPEN</span>
            <span x-show="!open">CLOSED</span>

        </div>

    </div>

<!-- The next component interacts with the upper component using events,
     even if it's external to it. This technique can also be applied 
     in nested components 
--> 
    <div style="min-width: 50%;margin-top: 3rem;border: 1px solid red;">

        <button x-data
                @click="$dispatch('open-close', { increment: 100 })"
        >
            OUTER-BUTTON
        </button>

    </div>

</div>
```

Also, nested components can access the parent's *$refs*

Comment: I see example of dispatch. How reference works any example?

Comment: Can I have example of x-subscribe or x-modelable or reference

Comment: @BLPraveen *x-modelable* allows the binding of properties of different ojects, but I have never used it. I don't remember an Alpine *x-subscribe* directive. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "reference", do you mean maybe *x-ref / $refs*?

Comment: Yes refrence means x-refs

Comment: [Here](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/ref) the documentation. *x-ref* is used to assign a an *internal Alpine object id-like* to have a direct access to the DOM (Alpine) elements. *The magic variable $refs* groups all defined *x-ref* for each *Alpine object*. Nested components can access to parent *$refs* component